# apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

After upgrade apache, restarting apache2 service give me that error

```
Starting web server: apache2AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for debian
```

What I did is: 
Edit `/etc/hosts` file and add

```
127.0.0.1 debian
```

After that error disapear. Did I do all right?

Answer (score 0):

[ServerName](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) should be set to a name that your server can resolve to an IP address. It is also good if your web servers clients can also resolve that address but not vital.

Your work around is acceptable as long as you are not using the name for [name based virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) or expecting apache to generate redirect url's.

The best solution is to have a real world DNS name that both you and people accessing the host can look up.